# Reading PDF files in PHP or JS, then extracting the contents, by text ideally

Tags: php, file, pdf

I have a task of reading pdf files after an upload in the DB or n a folder,

What is the question here is : How to read PDF files in PHP or JS, JQuery, AJAX, 
Then i want to recuperate the datas to inject in a form fields.

There's a lot of infos to do this process with text files but pdf seems complicated. There is a PHP class for that ? I'm not used to classes in Php but with infos, it would lead me.

Thanks a lot for help!! 
Have a grreat one!

Comment: Hi,Can you pls try in Google "TCPDF" i think it is useful to you http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

Comment: `tcpdf` is used for generating / rendering PDF files, but the OP wants wo read / analyse an existing pdf`s contents.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this using http://www.pdfparser.org/

I needed the specifications from a pdf file and get all the raw text. This is the code I used:

```
<?php
include 'pdfparser-master/vendor/autoload.php';
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('specs.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: Please mention the license (GPL) of this library as it's not useable in all cases because of its [incompatiblility to other licenses](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses).

Comment: Hi Robin, 
Thanks for your help. Yes, that's what i found on the web actually. I use a foreach loop to extract the keywords also. There is a little bug with some of my files, it shows up as a result ? on every space, some pdf files have perfect results too, even with images, graphics etc. It works really good but the ? are wierd. If anyone knows, that would be appreciated.